# Bring your posts for editing

Tags: discussion

Editing is an important part of getting questions and answers in the best condition they can be. If I see a post with some typos, or that could be worded more clearly, I edit it. However, there are two things slowing down this process of improving posts:

1. People who are happy to edit won't notice every opportunity (we have lots of posts).
2. People who notice editing opportunities won't always have the time/confidence to make the edit themselves.

How would you feel about having a community wiki meta post to which anyone can add a link to a question they'd like to see edited? Then someone can link to their own question or answer if they think it isn't quite worded right, or they could highlight a post from someone else that has excellent content but confusing sentence structure or spelling.

People could also come here when they feel like contributing to the site by improving posts, but don't want to trawl through everything trying to find posts that need editing. Just come here, pick up the top link, and then delete it from the list when you've edited it.

First I want to find out how the community feels about this and if it would cause any problems.

Comment: Oh, and please don't be offended by the downvotes, I think you had a good idea at heart, it just isn't the right circumstances for it to be edited.

Comment: @DonyorM thanks for the feedback. I can see what you mean, and from the upvotes so can others...

Answer (score 5):

I think this wouldn't be that useful, it would quickly get clogged with threads that people had edited but not cleared out, or posts that don't need actual editing. It is better that you just edit when it is needed during your normal rounds around the site. We should be able to do this, especially right now because we don't have a whole lot of traffic.

I'm also not sure how useful it would be. I know I regularly just read a post, and I would end it if it needed it.

Comment: Also, not everyone sees the same things as worth editing, or has the necessary domain knowledge to successfully edit.

Comment: I've seen questions that need editing but I don't edit as I feel I could simply make it worse. I would link it to an editing wiki though.